# Unsupported devices due to your manifest settings

Tags: android

Unsupported devices due to your manifest settings
This statement comes on developers page of market with few android devices listed under it.
What to do for that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.app" 
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="6.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/apple"
        android:label="myapp"
        android:debuggable="false">
        <activity android:name="com.myapp" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>
    <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true"/>
    <supports-screens  android:smallScreens="true"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: mean app is restricted for this configuration device ...

Comment: ya but how make app work on these devices

Comment: change the manifest for that "Show us your manifest here" as SpK suggested ............

Comment: Try removing both  <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true"/>
    <supports-screens  android:smallScreens="true"/>
and see now

Comment: can you let us alos know "Unsupported devices" device this you want to support

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to add `uses_feature`

e.g

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

This Specify a uses-feature node for every API feature used by your app. 
This lets Market hide your app from any device that doesn’t support the hardware features your app requires.

Comment: i have attached my menifest file.Please suggest me what changes should i make?

Comment: @SpK I have attched my menifest suggest me what changes should i need to do?